# Compiling with texmaker fails, compiling on commandline works

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker, paths

Hi I can compile my latex document using `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape Masterthesis.tex`

When I hit the quick compile button in textmaker however nothing happens. I noticed that the log in the texmaker log window shows the log I created when I compiled via the command line. Instead of compiling it shows me the old log file (I can tell it because the log shows when the command was issued, and its old).

In the settings the quick compile comand is set as follows: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`

In addition if I remove the files that were created during build and then hit the quick compile button, I get a "Could not start command" error.

What could be wrong?

This is the log file: http://pastebin.com/eA2w5YTT

Comment: I got this now and again, so finally installed rubber and configured QuickBuild to work with it.

Comment: Open TeXmaker-->Options-->Configure TeXmaker-->QuickBuild--> IS `pdflatex+viewpdf` **Checked on** assuming `bibtex` run is not required ? TeXmaker is _only_ IDE May be somewhat like a car without engine(pdflatex): Configuring TeXmaker for the right engine is _key_ part

Comment: @texenthusiast yes it's checked. i worked with texmaker on ubuntu 12.04 before and it worked like a charm. now i'm on ubuntu 13.04 with gnome3. don't know if it has something to do with it

Comment: i added the full path to the pdflatex command in the settings and now the quick compile command works (/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex) Although i'm wondering why it's working in the shell and not in texmaker? I added the path to latex in my .bashrc as ```export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"```. Is that the wrong place?

Comment: Set Path [Post-install actions](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-300003.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i now found the problem. i was exporting the path to texlive in my ~/.bashrc. This worked for my shell but apparently not for texmaker. I now export the path in ~/.profile and it works in shell and in texmaker (after restarting) (Note: I'm on ubuntu)